# How to get a string of max date from an array of string dates?

Tags: javascript

What would be the most elegant way to get max date from an array of strings like below?

```
var dates = ["2018-12-29T15:23:20.486695Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:21.613216Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:22.695710Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:24.013567Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:25.097649Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:26.692125Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:27.918561Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:29.217879Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:30.468284Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:31.548761Z"]
```

I have tried:

```
var timestamps = dates.map(date => Date.parse(date));
var max_date = Math.max.apply(Math, timestamps)
```

But this leaves me with a timestamp that I would need to convert back to the **exact** original format (and I don't know how to do that).
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date like strings and take the greater value.

```js
var dates = ["2018-12-29T15:23:20.486695Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:21.613216Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:22.695710Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:24.013567Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:25.097649Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:26.692125Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:27.918561Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:29.217879Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:30.468284Z", "2018-12-29T15:23:31.548761Z"],
    latest = dates.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);

console.log(latest);
```

Comment: True, those **particular** strings can be compared meaningfully as strings.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: do you mean that the strings have exactly the same format, thus can be compared alphabetically?

Comment: @Nina Scholz: do you mind explainig what does the function do? Is it "if a is larger than b, replace b with a"?

Comment: it takes a string comparison. and while the ISO format is made for comparing by string, without using additional helpers, the format is perfect for using it for string in [lexicographically order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). basically all needed units, like year, month, day and so on are in descending order and uses a pattern with leading zeroes. this in necessary to compare and for getting the right result without converting to epoch time or to other comparable units.

Comment: the taken callback of just a single [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with a check and two possible values is sufficient to get the maximum string out of the data set.

Comment: @barciewicz - Because the strings are in a format where the most significant fields are on the left and the least significant are on the right and the fields are fixed-width, yes. Whereas date strings in U.S. format (month/day/year) or European format (day/month/year) can **not** be compared meaningfully as strings.

Answer (score 0):

That's the format provided by `toISOString` on `Date`. So you take your timestamp value, feed it into `new Date`, and use `toISOString` on the result:

```
console.log(new Date(max_date).toISOString());
```

Example:

```js
var dates = [
"2018-12-29T15:23:20.486695Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:21.613216Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:22.695710Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:24.013567Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:25.097649Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:26.692125Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:27.918561Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:29.217879Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:30.468284Z",
"2018-12-29T15:23:31.548761Z"
];

var timestamps = dates.map(date => Date.parse(date));
var max_date = Math.max.apply(Math, timestamps)

console.log(new Date(max_date).toISOString());
```

Note that you get `"2018-12-29T15:23:31.548Z"` rather than `"2018-12-29T15:23:31.548761Z"` because you've parsed the strings to JavaScript dates, and JavaScript dates only hold milliseconds, not microseconds.